# Is JDK 6u14 Garbage First (G1) garbage collector, suitable for JRun?

Tags: coldfusion, jvm, java-6, jrun, g1gc

Garbage First (G1) garbage collector
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/opinali/archive/2009/02/here_comes_jdk.html

Do you think this garbage collector is better for JRun, running ColdFusion 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will tell you that updating the JVM in ColdFusion is a breeze, so I always update to the latest JVM once it's been released for a month. I haven't had any problems with any of the releases thus far and ColdFusion seems to be getting a little quicker with each update.

That said, you should always updated the JVM on a test machine first and run your battery of tests to make sure nothing breaks.

Comment: But I think G1 GC needs to be activated with a Flag in VM... So that's why I'm asking if any expert in JVM can tell me if this GC is meant good for running CF.

Comment: what are you afraid of. test it out. if it doesn't work out, just switch back the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

http://blog.alagad.com/2009/06/18/the-g1-garbage-collector/

Answer (score 1):

G1 is available in [Java 6 update 14](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u14.html#hotspot14.0-G1-6u14).  It might be a good choice from a technical perspective, but in this release, it has the following odd restriction:

> Although G1 is available for use in this release, note that production use of G1 is only permitted where a Java support contract has been purchased. G1 is supported thru Sun's Java Platform Standard Edition for Business program.

InfoQ has speculation about whether this is just a short term limitation or a long term attempt by Sun (now Oracle) to make some money: [Is Sun offering the new G1 Garbage Collector Only with a Paid Support Contract?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/g1-paid)

Comment: Regarding the speculation... As I understand it G1 is also in OpenJDK so I don't think they intend to keep it to themselves and paying customers.

Comment: They have updated the text on the download page to:
G1 is available as early access in this release, please try it and give us feedback. Usage in production settings without a Java SE for Business support contract is not recommended.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the solution you are looking for, read on garbage collectors:

http://training.figleaf.com/curriculum/upload/AdminCF800_Unit05_configuringPerformance.pdf

(see page 5-10)

```
<cfscript>
    obj = createObject("java", "java.lang.System");
    obj.gc();
    obj.runFinalization();
</cfscript>
```

Comment: This is not what the question was asking.